# Null pointer exception using null safe navigation operator

Tags: apex, null-pointer, null, safe-navigation-operator

Following scenario throws **nullptr exception** inside if condition block **!sample?.SomeField__c**:

```
MyObject__c sample = null;
if (!sample?.SomeField__c) {
   ...
}
```

Why is that? Shouldn't that be evaluated to `!(sample == null ? null : sample.SomeField__c)` ?

Comment: If you try to compile `if (!null) {` you get "! operator can only be applied to boolean expressions" as that is not a valid expression in Apex. Perhaps the thinking is better to output an NPE error in this case. Something like `if (sample?.SomeField__c === false) {` might be the way to go. Or probably better to add an extra line of code to establish the boolean value before the if.

Comment: @KeithC Thank you for clarification, do you know if there is a shorthand for checking if value is `null or false`?

Comment: `sample?.SomeField__c !== true` maybe.

Comment: `Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: NULL, Boolean.`
I think that using simple inequality operator will be enough :)

Comment: Maybe. Or `(Boolean) sample?.SomeField__c !== true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is compiled to essentially `if(sample == null? null: sample.SomeField__c)`. However, `if(null)` isn't valid. Just compare to true or false depending on your need.

```
if(sample?.SomeField__c == true) {
```

Or:

```
if(sample?.SomeField__c != false) {
```

etc.

Even considering that you have to do a comparison, the net construct is still shorter than the original version:

```
// Shorter
if(sample?.SomeField__c == true) {
// Longer.
if(sample != null && sample.SomeField__c) {
```